# ProxyDroid not working

Tags: proxy

I am using connectify + proxy droid, yet only proxydroid seems to connect to the internet, while nothing else works.

Proxydroid connects in the sense that, it loads ads.

Nothing else works.

I'm rooted.

Is there any alternative way to set system wide proxy access? Nothing seems to be working. I tried autoproxy also.

Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm. Did you definitely tick the 'Transparent Proxy' option? That tells it to make everything go through the proxy.

Another thing I have noticed when using it is that it can be quite specific with a proxy - my school uses microsoft tmg, and has the proxy as 'tmg' in browsers, but proxydroid needs the full URL to the system (which is TMG.academy.(myschoolwebsiteurl).co.uk)

Comment: You're the [G.O.A.T](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=goat) ! Thanks man.

Comment: Had you not ticked it? An easy mistake to make :)